# passing a url variable to a php session at a mouse click

Tags: url, session

I have a table with click able rows. What I like to do is to  add the value in $value1['inc_index'] to a session variable. 
I tried $var1 = $value1['inc_index'] and various other formats with no success.

```
<td> <a class='tablelink' href='../layout/details.php?inc_id=". $value1['inc_index']. " '>" . $value1['inc_index'] . "</a> </td>
```

how do i go about modifying the above line so that the $value1['inc_index'] is **also** passed to a session variable or pass inc_id to a session variable before moving on to the next page.

thanks

Comment: You want to store the inc_id selected by the user in a session variable?

Comment: yes i like to pass inc_id to a session before moving to the next page.

Comment: You have only one like or the table have multiple rows?

Comment: the table has multiple rows

Comment: So, you cannot know what link the user will click on, therefore you cannot set the variable before the user click on the link. What you can do, is capture the inc_id the user clicked on after and set in the session variable in your details.php file.

Comment: I Babblo, thanks for your help... I tried that.. my detail page has the option to submit a comments so when the user clicks the button to save the comment the details page is reload in turn it losses the url variable inc_id. so when the page reloads the url variable is lost so the sessoin variable is reassigned a blank variable. hope i explained it correctly